# Laravel get all array of parent categories with id and title

Tags: php, laravel

In one of `laravel` models i can get all category parent names with this code,

```php
public function getParentsNames()
{
    if ($this->parent) {
        return $this->parent->getParentsNames() . " > " . $this->title;
    } else {
        return $this->title;
    }
}
```

this function return `4` parent of selected category but now i want to have `id` with title, for example:

```php
public function getParentsNamesArray()
{
    if ($this->parent) {
          return $this->parent->getParentsNamesArray()[][]=[
              "id" => $this->id,
              "title" => $this->title
          ];
    } else {
        return [
            "id" => $this->id,
            "title" => $this->title
        ];
    }
}

public function parent(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(ProductCategory::class, 'category_id');
}
```

this my code return one array and couldn't return all parent in end

Answer (score 0):

i fount the solution :

```php
public function getParentsNamesArray() {
    $parents = collect([]);
    if($this->parent) {
        $parent = $this->parent;
        while(!is_null($parent)) {
            $parents->push($parent);
            $parent = $parent->parent;
        }
        return $parents;
    } else {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```